# How do I export a concatenated csv with utf-8 error

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate a few csv files and am getting a utf-8 error, not sure what it means. Basically I have 7 "pm" files (number 12-18), and I want to concatenate them all. I am pretty much there, but as I am trying to export, I get a utf-8 error, and I am not sure what to do because I don't know what it means. The following is the relevant code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
from glob import glob
from os import chdir

#import data frames
pm18 = pd.read_csv('pm18.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1', low_memory=False)
pm17 = pd.read_csv('pm17.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1', low_memory=False)
pm16 = pd.read_csv('pm16.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1', low_memory=False)
pm15 = pd.read_csv('pm15.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1', low_memory=False)
pm14 = pd.read_csv('pm14.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1', low_memory=False)
pm13 = pd.read_csv('pm13.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1', low_memory=False)
pm12 = pd.read_csv('pm12.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1',low_memory=False)


   #list files in directory
    csv_file_path = (r'C:\Users\EDraklellis\Desktop\FebruaryDownloads\FebruaryDownloads')
    chdir(csv_file_path)
    # List all CSV files in the working dir
    file_pattern = ".csv"
    list_of_files = [file for file in glob(os.path.join(csv_file_path,'*.csv'))]
    print(list_of_files)

#concatenate listed files
file_out = 'mergell84.csv'
def produceOneCSV(list_of_files, file_out):
# Consolidate all CSV files into one object
    result_obj = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in list_of_files])
    result_obj.to_csv(file_out, index=False, encoding='utf-8')

produceOneCSV(list_of_files, file_out)
```

this line produces the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-bea8878ce7aa> in <module>
----> 1 produceOneCSV(list_of_files, file_out)

<ipython-input-112-e94873c1017a> in produceOneCSV(list_of_files, file_out)
      3 def produceOneCSV(list_of_files, file_out):
      4 # Consolidate all CSV files into one object
----> 5     result_obj = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in list_of_files])
      6     result_obj.to_csv(file_out, index=False, encoding='utf-8')

<ipython-input-112-e94873c1017a> in <listcomp>(.0)
      3 def produceOneCSV(list_of_files, file_out):
      4 # Consolidate all CSV files into one object
----> 5     result_obj = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in list_of_files])
      6     result_obj.to_csv(file_out, index=False, encoding='utf-8')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    683         )
    684 
--> 685         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    686 
    687     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    455 
    456     # Create the parser.
--> 457     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    458 
    459     if chunksize or iterator:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    893             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    894 
--> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    896 
    897     def close(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1133     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1134         if engine == "c":
-> 1135             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1136         else:
   1137             if engine == "python":

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1915         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1916 
-> 1917         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1918         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1919 

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 16: invalid start byte
```

Comment: You are reading the files twice, right? First, you read them individually (`pm18 = ...` etc.), then again in the list comprehension inside the `produceOneCSV` function – are these the same files? The first time you use Latin-1 for decoding, which seems to work, but the second time you use the default, which is apparently UTF-8 and doesn't work.

Comment: `ISO-8859-1` a.k.a. `latin1` can read *any* file and it may or may not actually be `latin1`, but the file clearly isn't UTF-8-encoded from the error.  Read the file with the correct encoding, whatever it is.